# git - How to undo changes to a locally committed file

Tags: git, git-commit, revert

I did following, all while on my local `BranchA`:

1. Modify `FileA` (by mistake)
2. `git add FileA`
3. `git commit -m "Modified FileA"`

So, `FileA` is in my local commit (never pushed to remote) on my local branch `BranchA` (also never pushed to remote).

How do I revert changes to FileA?

**UPDATE AND HOW I SOLVED IT**

I undoed changes to FileA from SourceTree instead from git as I realized it is simpler for me.

To do so, in SourceTree, r-c on commited file FileA > "Log Select ..." > select the previous commit (the one before yours) > r-c on it and choose "Reset to this commit". That did the job but thank you all

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-do-i-undo-the-most-recent-commits-in-git

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To specifically undo the changes in that file but keep the commit unchanged otherwise :

**1) Revert fileA to its previous state**

```
git checkout HEAD^ -- path/to/fileA
```

**2) Include that in the last commit you did on BranchA**

```
git commit --amend
```

(And since it has not been pushed yet, no need to push with force next time.)

Comment: Because `git checkout HEAD^ -- path/to/fileA` writes the file to the index first, then to the work-tree, you actually don't need the `git add` step here. But this is otherwise the shortest (and probably best) set of Git commands to use; upvoted...

Comment: Thanks, I accept your answer but havent had chance to try since I did it from SourceTree instead.  In SourceTree, r-c on committed file > Log Select ... > select the previous commit (the one before yours) > r-c on it and choose "Reset to this commit".  That did the job but thank you all

Answer (score 3):

First you reset your branch to the previous commit:

```
git reset @^ --mixed
```

Then you can use `checkout` to reset specific files to the old state:

```
git checkout -- files...
```

Once you have done that you can re-commit your changes:

```
git add files...
git commit -m "message"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reset the current branch index to the previous commit with `git reset HEAD~1`. Add `--hard` to reset your working directory, or leave it off if you want to refine the changes and recommit.

If you have other changes that you made since then, use `git rebase` to move your offending commit to the top of the stack first.

Comment: But I want only that one File to be undoed, not entire commit.  I have FileA, FileB, FileC in that commit, I want only FileA to be reverted to version before my change

Comment: So leave off the --hard, so you can refine (git checkout -- FileA) and recommit.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it (I assume your commit has changes only in files, you want to discard):

Being in your BranchA

```
git rebase -i HEAD~2
```

It will give a list of two commits, sorted historically asc. The last one is what you would like to change. So, you want to discard that commit. Move cursor to the second commit, and instead of `pick` type `drop`, or just `d`.

Save your changes (depends on your editor, it could be `CTRL`+`X` + `SHIFT`+`Y` for `nano` or `:wq` for `vim`, and that is it.